# How can we change the HTML table contents dynamically using javascript through modal-dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I change the tablecell value dynamically through using of jquery modal-dialog. I created the table using javascript. Here I added the code which will display the table cell value through dialog. In this code it will show the table cell value in text box, that I can change it but I can't save it.

```
$(function () {

    $(function(){
    $("#inttbl td").click(function(){
    var selectValue;
    selectValue = $(this).html();
    $("#select_cell_display_div").html("Edit The Value<br><br><input type='text' id='namefield' value='"+selectValue+"'>");
    $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog
            ({
            height: 240,
            modal: true,
              buttons: {
                "Save": function(){
                console.log('save clicked');
                    var select= document.getElementById('namefield').value
                    alert(select);
                    }
                }
            });
            });
    });
```

Html code is:

```
<div id="dialog-modal" title="Selected Value">
<span id="select_cell_display_div"></span> 
</div>`
```

Comment: Why `$(function(){` 2 times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to cache your initial DOM lookup of the cell that was clicked so you can set the cell value:

```
$(function () {
    $("#inttbl td").click(function (e) {
        var cell = $(this), // cache lookup
            selectValue = cell.html();
        $("#select_cell_display_div").html("Edit The Value<br><br><input type='text' id='namefield' value='" + selectValue + "'>");
        $("#dialog-modal").dialog({
            height: 240,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Save": function () {
                    console.log('save clicked');
                    var select = document.getElementById('namefield').value
                    alert(select);
                    cell.html(select); // use cached lookup to set the cell value
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```